# Increase values in array in specific way in java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, sequence

I want to create a program that it will take as an input how many categories we will have, for example 3.

```
int [] n=new int[4];
n[1]=0; n[2]=0; n[3]=0;
```

Then it will ask for the maximum values for each one, for example:

```
int [] max=new int[4];
max[1]=2;
max[2]=4;
max[3]=3;
```

I want to make a sequence of numbers based on their max values. For example when `n[3]==3;` then the `n[2]++;` until it reaches its max value and then n[1]. I want the result to be like this:

```
n[1]    n[2]    n[3]
0        0       0
0        0       1
0        0       2
0        0       3
0        1       0
```

Until it reaches the values `n[1]=2, n[2]=4, n[3]=3`.

An example of output would be this:

```
From array slot #0: 0
From array slot #1: 0
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 1
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 2
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 3
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #0: 1
From array slot #1: 0
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 1
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 2
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2

From array slot #1: 3
From array slot #2: 0
From array slot #2: 1
From array slot #2: 2
```

My biggest problem is that i want to do it dynamically. To be more specific, I want to change the given categories, for example to ask for 4 cat, and their max values, but to keep the same logic.

I hope you can help me with this. And sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are ignoring the 0th position in the arrays on purpose?

Comment: no.. this is not my problem. I can fix that by just adding +1 on the array position. Check my question on the first post because, since I am a new member I can't answer my question. I edited the first one to see what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this doesn't help, not really too sure on what your goal is, but what you're trying to do is:

1. Iterate through an array (size of 3), starting at its last slot `[2]`, and ending at its first slot `[0]`.
2. For each slot, print to the console from 0 to the value in that spot (from 0 to 3 the first time)

If so, take a look at this:

```
static int[] array = new int[3];
public static void main(String[] args) {
     array[0] = 2;
     array[1] = 4;
     array[2] = 3;

     printSequence(array.length);
}

static void printSequence(int howManyMaxes) {
    for(int i = howManyMaxes-1; i >= 0; i--) { //loops through array (from last to first)
         for(int counter = 0; counter < array[i]; counter++) { //loops from 0 to value
              System.out.println("From array slot #"+i+": "+counter);
         }
    }
}
```

As for formatting it, that's your decision. Mess around with it a bit, you'll become familiar with it.

It counts in an array-like style. If the max is 2, the result will be '0, 1', not '1, 2'.
To change this, change where your counter starts, and instead of `counter < array[i]`, the condition needs to be `counter <= array[i]`